# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS error when installing Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am unable to install the Mysql repositories because of this error

Err:11 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/mssql-server-2019 focal Release
404  Not Found [IP: 13.107.246.33 443]
Obter:12 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/mssql-server-2022 jammy/main amd64 Packages [2.430 B]

Comment: MYSQL is not MSSQL. That server is dead so find a working one directory